# Dynamic 2D Array Initialization

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to create  and initialize a 2D array but the initialization is failed. I encounter "The program has unexpectedly finished." in Qt Creator.

What is wrong?

**in .h file**

```
private:
    int pop;
    int d;
    float **uye;
```

**in .cpp file**

```
pop=50;
d=12;
uye = new float*[pop];
for(int i=0; i<d; i++) uye[i] = new float[d];

for(int n=0; n<pop; n++)
{
    for(int m=0; m<d; m++)
    {
        uye[n][m] = (float) n*m;
    }
}
```

Comment: A 2D jagged array with dimensions determined at runtime that doesn't leak: `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop `for(int i=0; i<d; i++)` should probably be `for(int i=0; i<pop; i++)`. Otherwise, you are only reserving space for 12 elements, but later try to access 50.

Note that having raw pointer members is considered a very bad idea in modern C++, because you need to worry about copying semantics. Better use a flat `std::vector<float>` and do the 2D to 1D mapping manually, or use a `std::vector<std::vector<float> >` with convenient access syntax.

I would prefer the second version. Without seeing more context:

```
pop = 50;
d = 12;
uye = std::vector<std::vector<float> >(pop, std::vector<float>(d));
```

The nested for loops that follow work exactly the same, no changes required.

Answer (score 3):

> What is wrong?

You're not using `std::vector` (that's one of the things that's wrong, @FredO covered the other thing).

```
#include <vector>

int main(){
  typedef std::vector<float> inner_vec;
  typedef std::vector<inner_vec> outer_vec;

  int pop = 50, d = 12;
  // first parameter to vector is its size
  // second is what every element should be initialized to
  outer_vec uye(pop, inner_vec(d));
  for(unsigned n = 0; n < uye.size(); ++n){
    for(unsigned m = 0; m < uye[n].size(); ++m){
      uye[n][m] = (float)n*m;
    }
  }
}
```